# How to setup wasm-vips for next.js/react apps?

Tags: webpack, next.js, webassembly, vips

I'm trying to use [wasm-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/wasm-vips) library for my next.js project. When I'm starting file from pure node it works fine, but I want to use it on front-end and that's where problems begins. I'm starting constantly getting errors:
[image: screenshot with next.js error]
I set up headers to make possible using sharedArrayBuffer, and they're working properly
[image: next.js config]
crossOriginIsolated is true
[image]
Other approach to import throws different error
[image]
[image]

So in general I understand that it's problem with import or webpack settings but I'm stuck and currently don't know how to fix them

I tried different imports, placing files from library in different places, environments, and it works well for node, but not so well for next.js even basic starter project

Comment: Cross-posted and answered here: https://github.com/kleisauke/wasm-vips/issues/50